# Cancelling a task throws 'A task was cancelled' AggregateException. Why?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I created a simple TaskManager that keeps track of running tasks and their cancellation tokens.  My code snippet uses it to cancel the specified tasks, I then wait until they complete.  Straightforward and my code works - almost - as expected.

The unexplainable part of the code is the `Task.WaitAll` call.  It throws an `AggregateException` with three 'A task was cancelled' inner exception.  This is true of course, but why does it throw an exception?  Here is the code:

```
internal void StopProcessor()
{       
    try
    {   
        var taskList = _taskManager.CancelTask(new string[] { "InboundProcessor", "OutboundProcessor", "MainProcessor" });
        
        Task.WaitAll(taskList, 2000);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        foreach (var t in _taskManager.GetAllTasks())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Task ID={t.Task.Id}, status={t.Task.Status}, cancelled={t.Task.IsCanceled}, completed={t.Task.IsCompleted}, faulted={t.Task.IsFaulted}");
        }
    }
}
```

When I check the task status details in the catch block, I get the result I expected, all tasks have a status=cancelled, completed=True and no fault:

- Task ID=17, status=Canceled, cancelled=True, completed=True, faulted=False
- Task ID=19, status=Canceled, cancelled=True, completed=True, faulted=False
- Task ID=21, status=Canceled, cancelled=True, completed=True, faulted=False

I don't understand the reason for this behavior, can someone educate me and tell me how to improve this code?  Thanks.

Comment: cancellation almost always presents as an exception, as it isn't the expected success outcome; this should simply be expected, if cancellation is a possibility

Comment: Note that it's also behaving exactly [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WaitAll_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___): "(Throws) AggregateException: At least one of the Task instances was canceled. If a task was canceled, the AggregateException exception contains an OperationCanceledException exception in its InnerExceptions collection. -or- An exception was thrown during the execution of at least one of the Task instances."

Comment: (So I don't think it's really unexplainable. It's explained by "working as intended" even if that's not "working as expected before reading the docs".)

Answer (score 3):

[From the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WaitAll_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___)

> AggregateException
> **At least one of the Task instances was canceled. If a task was canceled, the AggregateException exception contains an OperationCanceledException exception in its InnerExceptions collection.**
>
> -or-
>
> An exception was thrown during the execution of at least one of the Task instances.